# Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Click Element' expected 1 to 3 arguments, got 0

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I'm trying to select the first item from the list below using robotframework:

```
<select id="organization_saml_enabled" name="organization[saml_enabled]">
   <option value="true">SAML SSO enabled</option>
   <option value="false" selected="selected">SAML SSO disabled</option>
</select>
```

With this snippet:

```
Click Element  //select[@id="organization_saml_enabled"]/option[@value="true"]
```

I get the error `Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Click Element' expected 1 to 3 arguments, got 0.`

I dont get it because from the way i understand the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Click%20Element) the Click Element needs the locator and optional offsets. 
Can anyone help me check what I'm missing here.

Comment: I honestly don't think it's possible to get that exact error with that exact line of code. Are you absolutely certain that it's this specific line of code which causes this exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add locator strategy (`xpath:`) before the actual locator and remember to have at least two spaces between keyword and argument:

```
Click Element    xpath://select[@id="organization_saml_enabled"]/option[@value="true"]
```

Comment: I also noticed that if i used the `Run Keywords` and chain that key word with another one the keyword failed. That is what maybe was causing the issue so i decided to split the keywords and execute them separately instead on chaining them based on a certain condition.

Comment: In `Run Keywords` case, you'll have to use `AND` between keywords.

E.g.: `Run Keywords    Keyword1   argument    AND    Keyword2    argument2    argument3`

Answer (score 0):

dont use Selenium2Library, use SeleniumLibrary latest version.

Comment: [so] is not a forum. This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: The issue could of also been to this to, as the keywords differ in these versions. This was intended as a 'partial answer'///